# Error Connecting Skill to Virtual Assistant Using Botskills Connect

Tags: typescript, azure, botframework

I am running into multiple errors when trying to connect a sample skill to a sample virtual assistant. Both are in typescript and run correctly on their own, but when I run `botskills connect` I encounter the following errors:

I first run botskills connect with the --localManifest parameter (`-l`):

```
botskills connect -l "C:\VA\latest-skill\src\manifest\manifest-1.1.json" --ts
```

This returns an error saying to include a path to the Luis Folder:

```
Updating Dispatch
Adding skill to Dispatch
node.exe : There was an error while connecting the Skill to the Assistant:
At C:\npm\botskills.ps1:15 char:3
+   & "node$exe"  "$basedir/node_modules/botskills/lib/botskills.js" $a ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (There was an er... the Assistant::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Error: An error ocurred while updating the Dispatch model:
Error: Path to the LUIS folder (C:\VA\latest-assistant\Deployment\Resources\Skills) leads to a nonexistent folder.
Remember to use the argument '--luisFolder' for your Skill's LUIS folder.
```

Then I try including the `--luisFolder` argument, and get an error to use the --dispatchFolder argument:

```
Updating Dispatch
Adding skill to Dispatch
node.exe : There was an error while connecting the Skill to the Assistant:
At C:\npm\botskills.ps1:15 char:3
+   & "node$exe"  "$basedir/node_modules/botskills/lib/botskills.js" $a ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (There was an er... the Assistant::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Error: An error ocurred while updating the Dispatch model:
Error: Path to the Dispatch folder (C:\VA\latest-assistant\Deployment\Resources\Dispatch\en-us) leads to a nonexistent folder.
Remember to use the argument '--dispatchFolder' for your Assistant's Dispatch folder.
```

There is no such folder in the sample skill code generated in Typescript - this is what the folder structure looks like:

[image: Skill Deployment Folder]

This is where I am stuck currently. Can a dispatch folder be manually created? Is there another way around this parameter? Any further guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please follow the below link to connect a skill. https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/tutorials/add-prebuilt-skill/4-connect-skill/

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Ram's comment: Your command is pointing at a 'local' manifest:

`botskills connect -l  "C:\VA\latest-skill\src\manifest\manifest-1.1.json" --ts`

when it should be your deployed skill location:

`botskills connect --remoteManifest "https://<YOUR_SKILL_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/manifest/manifest-1.1.json" --ts`

Make sure your skill is deployed before attempting to connect it to your VA. Once it's deployed, run the botskills connect command with it pointed at your deployed manifest.